# Find the subrepresentation of a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

This is a spin-off of this question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636682/show-that-representation-rho-can-be-divided

I came across the problem of dividing representation $\rho$ of a cyclic group given as below:
$$
g \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & -1 \\
     1 & 0  \\  
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
g^2 \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}
     0 & -1 \\
     1 & -1  \\  
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
g^3 \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}
     -1 & 0 \\
     0 & -1  \\  
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
g^4 \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}
     -1 & 1 \\
     -1 & 0  \\  
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
g^5 \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}
     0 & 1 \\
     1 & -1  \\  
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
1 \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 0 \\
     0 & 1  \\  
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

into two irreducible representations.

Formally the task is to:

Reduce this representation to a direct sum of irreducible representations and find the matrix representation of $\rho$ in a new basis that's a sum of the basis of the found irreducible representations

How I think this one of the subrepresentation should look like (in case of the second subrepresentation it should be to the negative power):

$$\rho^1: \ 1 \longmapsto 1 \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  g \longmapsto \lambda \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ g^3 \longmapsto \lambda^3 \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ g^4 \longmapsto \lambda^4 \\  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ g^5 \longmapsto \lambda^5$$

Then, by Matschke's theorem the initial subrepresentation would look like this:

$$
g \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}
     \lambda & 0 \\
     0 & \lambda^{-1}  \\  
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
g^2 \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}
     \lambda^2 & 0 \\
     0 & \lambda^{-2}  \\  
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
g^3 \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}
     \lambda^3 & 0 \\
     0 & \lambda^{-3}  \\  
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
g^4 \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}
     \lambda^4 & 0 \\
     0 & \lambda^{-4}  \\  
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
g^5 \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}
     \lambda^5 & 0 \\
     0 & \lambda^{-5}  \\  
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
1 \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 0 \\
     0 & 1  \\  
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: This doesn't make sense as a representation.  $1$ should map to the identity matrix.  Otherwise, if it made sense, you would take the traces of the matrices and find an integer linear combination of traces of the irreducible representations to determine the decomposition.  (You "split" or "reduce" a representation, rather than "divide.")

Comment: Those summands are necessarily one-dimensional. In a 1-dimensional space a group can only act by scalars. Those scalars are eigenvalues of the matrices. Why don't you find an eigenbasis of $g$, and see what comes out?

Comment: I fixed the question and added some calculations - after finding the eigenvalues i tried to find the spanning vector but without any positive result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that you have the wrong eigenvalues. The characteristic polynomial for $g$ is $\lambda^2-\lambda+1$ and has eigenvalues
$$\lambda=\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}=e^{2\pi i/6}$$
and
$$\overline{\lambda}=\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}=e^{-2\pi i/6}=\lambda^{-1}.$$
Now, let $\{x,y\}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$ for which $g$ acts by the matrix
$$
g=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
You want a basis of eigenvectors, so you want a vector $v=ax+by$ such that 
$$\lambda v=g.v=g.(ax+by)=(a-b)x+ay.$$
This gives the equations
$$\begin{cases} \lambda a=a-b\\\lambda b=a\end{cases}.$$
A solution to this system is $a=\lambda$ and $b=1$, and we get and eigenvector
$$v=\lambda x+y.$$
Similarly,
$$w=\lambda^{-1}x+y$$
is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda^{-1}$. Reverting to column vector notation, the basis
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\lambda\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}\lambda^{-1}\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
decomposes your representation into two 1-dimensional invariant subspaces.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why did you find the vector v the way you did? From what I've been told i should check it with this condition $(g-\lambda I)v=0$ ?

Comment: The equation $(g-\lambda).v=0$ is the same as $g.v=\lambda v$.

Comment: If you need further help, please tell me where you are getting confused. Which line? That will help me answer your question.

Comment: I am confused with why is my reasoning wrong: $\begin{pmatrix}1 -\lambda&-1\\1&- \lambda \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$, so i get $(1-\lambda)x-y=0$ and $x-\lambda y=0$, from which i get $(1-\lambda)\lambda y-y=0$ and $y(-\lambda^2+\lambda-1)=0$

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, you just aren't making useful conclusions. You have the equation $x-\lambda y=0$. What does that tell you? It is also worth noting that 1-\lambda=\lambda^{-1}$, so the system has a consistent solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but so far I only have two 1-dimensional invariant subspaces and what I need is  to find the representations in those subspaces - with that find the matrix representation of my basis representation should be rather easy.

Comment: I think you need to think about what it means to find "the representations in those subspaces". How does $g$ act on $v$ and $w$? What is the matrix for $g$ in that basis?

Comment: I updated the question with how I understand it should look like.

Comment: Can you write the matrix for $g$ in the basis $\{v,w\}$ above? This can be obtained by conjugating by the matrix $$P=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&1\\1&\lambda^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$$ but hopefully you can identify the final answer without making this computation.

Comment: Normally i would find $P^{-1}$ and multiply $P^{-1}GP$, and get the matrix in the new basis, but i cannot do it since $detP=0$. Also is the subrepresentation $\rho^1$ correct?

Comment: Sorry. I wrote the wrong $P$. It should be $$P=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&\lambda^{-1}\\1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ You should calculate $PGP^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok, i finally calulated it - it doesn't look nice, but w/e. Once more - are the one dimensional subrepresentations I wrote correct? In what other way could I get the answer without calculating the inverse matrix?

Comment: could you please help me with the last question? I really want to know if I got the subrepresentations right. Also you said that I can with the matrix for g in the new basis without the said computation - what would be an easier way for it?

Comment: Since $gv=\lambda v$ and $gw=\lambda w$ the matrix for $g$ in the basis $\{v,w\}$ is $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&0\\0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}$. It is possible this should be $P^{-1}GP$. Is this what you got?

Comment: No the result i get from $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda& 1 \\ -\lambda^{-1} &1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & \lambda\\1&0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\lambda&\lambda^{-1}\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ is different from the result you wrote. Also i think that $gw=\lambda^{-1}w$, so the matrix should be $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&0\\0&\lambda^{-1} \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: You are right. The correct computation is actually $P^{-1}GP$. To see this, note that $Px=v$ ($x=(1,0)^T$), and $Gv=\lambda v$, so $$P^{-1}GPx=P^{-1}Gv=P^{-1}(\lambda v)=\lambda P^{-1}v=\lambda x$$